# MATLAB ODE45: Why is there a big divergence between analytical and numerical solution?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations, ode45

at the moment I try to understand ode45. So I would like to solve an exercise.
The differential equation is: y=y' with y(0)=10.
I wrote this code:

```
tspan = [0 5];
y0 = 10;

[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y) y, tspan, y0);
plot(t,y);
```

I know that the analytical solution would be the exponential-function. So I inserted it in the plot to verify the solution. (The exp function needs to be shifted by 9 upwards.)

```
hold on;
fplot(@(x) exp(x)+9,tspan,'r')
```

But there is a divergence I cannot explain. What I've understand wrong?

[red:analytical solution, blue: numerical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmnv9.png)

Comment: exp(5) = 148,4.... So the red curve is right. The blue curve on the other hand says exp(5) = 1500. That is a big difference. The diveregence should be something like 0.1 or so.

Comment: This is only the scale. Are you saying that such a gigantic error is normal? Since I do not expect this I assume an error on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The true solution of this diffential equation with this initial condition is : `10*exp(t)`

for `y'(t) = y(t)`
the solution is of the form `c.exp(t)` with c a constant.
Using the initial condition : `y0 = 10`
We have : `c exp(0) = 10`
therefore `c = 10`;

Therefore you are not comparing the correct amount,
Use : `fplot(@(x) 10*exp(x),tspan,'r')`